# How to access AWS Lightsail MySQL database from VPC (EC2 instance)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-lightsail

- I have an Amazon Lightsail MySQL database.
- I have enabled "VPC Peering" in Amazon Lightsail account.
- I have an EC2 server in the VPC account that is "peered" with Lightsail.

Now I want to access the Lightsail database from the EC2 instance. I know the "easy way" is to enable the "Public mode" in the Lightsail database. In this way, the endpoint is publicly available on Internet, so you can connect from anywhere.

I want to avoid this, so here is the question: Is it possible to access the Lightsail database from the EC2 instance, using the internal VPC communication? If not, is there any other way to make this connection more secure? Maybe a way to whitelist IPs in Lightsail databases?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reproduce your situation, I did the following:

- Launched an Amazon Lightsail Database (I chose PostgreSQL)
- Enabled VPC Peering in the Lightsail console (Account / Advanced)
- Launched an Amazon EC2 instance in the **Default VPC** (which is the only one that Lightsail connects to)
- Tried connecting from the EC2 instance to the Lightsail database

It did not work.

The database DNS Name successfully resolved to an IP address that was in the correct range for VPC Peering. However, when attempting to connect to the database, `psql` hung for a long time before failing. This is an indication of **no network connection** between the EC2 instance and the Lightsail database.

Normally, the way to fix it would be to check the Security Groups, but Lightsail does not support security groups. It would appear that access to the Lightsail database is locked-down to the Lightsail network and it is not accessible via VPC Peering.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply! At least I have "confirmation" that is not possible (or that someone else tried and it could not do it).